# Microsoft Graph dotNet sdk Thread Safe?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, microsoft-graph-api

Is the Graph dotNet sdk implemented Thread-Safe in all Areas?

E.g. Multiple Worker Threads want to retrieve user EMails:

```
var request = graphClient.Users[usrId].Messages.Request().Top(top).Select(select).Skip(10);
var result = await request.GetAsync();
```

Sending/executing Requests should be Thread-Safe as each of them is exceuted in their own task.
But Is the creation of Requests implemented Thread-Safe?

So my Questions are

- Is the creation of Requests in sdk Thread-Safe?
- and Is the access to the graph client instance Thread-Safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the .Net Graph Client library is not implemented thread-safe in all areas. From a quick review of the library code, the [BaseClient](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Graph.Core/Requests/BaseClient.cs#L43) baseUrl is settable which could enable a scenario where two threads are accessing that variable. This could result in requests being made to unexpected baseUrls. Once a request has been built past the baseUrl provided by the GraphServiceClient, the creation of request is expected to be thread safe.

Regarding access to the Graph client instance and thread safety, if I understand correctly, that is a matter of how you design your application's access to the library.

Comment: Michael, could you clarify this asked in other way: what's the best practice for using graph client instance in a multithreaded application? To be more concrete, consider an ASP.NET Core application, where many requests need to access graph api. I use DI to inject graph client. What should be it lifetime to be safe (singleton, scoped(usually safe) or even transient)? Not only I'm concerned with memory allocation, but also with internal HttpClient pooling.

Comment: is this still valid ?

Comment: As @sich had mentioned what lifetime type is the best option for GraphServiceClient?

Comment: In terms of lifetime, it should be used as a singleton per Microsoft Graph endpoint. If your application supports [multiple cloud deployments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/deployments?view=graph-rest-1.0), you will want a single instance of GraphServiceClient per target endpoint.